# Mahout recommendation returns an empty list

Tags: java, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I'm using Play framework to create an e-commerce application.I have a table named Rating containing userId,ProductId,rating.
Now i'am trying to implement the mahout recommendation system to my application i tried the demo  [here](https://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/userbased-5-minutes.html)  and it works perfectly.So i'm trying now to get it to work with my actual data which i exported in a csv file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yokidara01/e-commerce/master/dataToRecommendation.csv) 
Finally when i run the method i don't get any recommendation , an empty list...,  here's my code :

```
public Result MahoutRecCSV(){
    List<Rating> ratings = Rating.find.all();
    /** From rating datatable to CVS file **/
   try {
       List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();//Arrays.asList("The first line", "The second line");
       for (Rating r : ratings){
           lines.add(r.user.id+","+r.produit.id+","+r.note);
       }
       Path file = Paths.get("dataToRecommendation.csv");
       Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

   }catch (IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

    /**Get REcommandation From the file created*/
    try {
        DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("dataToRecommendation.csv"));
        UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model);
        UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, model);
        UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);

        List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(3, 3);
        for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
            System.out.println(recommendation);
        }
        return ok(Json.toJson(recommendations));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TasteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ok("Erreur");
}
```

Comment: and your question is?...

Comment: sorry i edited the question , i get empty list , no recommendation